# Excel 2013: Condition Formatting with "IF(AND)" and "ISBLANK" and Data Validation Values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a formatted table and would like to use conditional formatting to shade in cells in a column (G) based on the following conditions:

1. Value in column (D) must say "Pending Decommission". The value is from a data validation list. If value does not match, do nothing.
2. If the above is true, then check to see if value in column (G) is blank.
3. If both are true, then insert value "Need Deletion Date" with the appropriate cell shading. If both or either one of the above is not true, then do nothing. I've tried a few nested IFs Ands and IsBlanks but can't seem to get it to work.

I current have this in the conditional formatting formula for cell G2. Of course I would like to apply this to the entire column.

```
=IF($D$2="Pending Decommission", IF(ISBLANK($G$2)=TRUE,"Insert Deletion Date",""),"")
```

Comment: Try this one: `=IF(AND($D2="Pending Decommission", ISBLANK($G2)), "Insert Deletion Date","")`

Comment: And to be clear, this is a formula that you fill down. Then in your conditional formatting menu, you can just set two colors, one for "Insert Deletion Date", and one for blank cells.

Comment: When I tried this, I got a circular reference warning. Let me try to make it more clear. I already have data in column G in some cells, but not all. I'm trying to insert a custom message in the blank cells asking for the user to input a date if the value in the referenced "D" column cell is selected as "Pending Decommission" from the Data Validation list. Perhaps this doesn't need conditional formatting at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two distinct requirements.

1. Assuming G2 is blank, filter on ColumnG to select banks and in G2 enter:

   `=IF($D2="Pending Decommission","Insert Deletion Date","")`

and copy down to suit. If G2 is not selected by the filter, adjust the row number for the formula accordingly.

2. Select ColumnG, clear any existing Conditional Formatting from it and HOME > Styles > Conditional Formatting > Highlight Cells Rules > Equal To...:

   `Insert Deletion Date`

and <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Adjust the formatting to suit. This will format any cell containing that text in ColumnG before the addition of the formula above.